# How do I safely sync a contained object (Menu Item) with an API that requires the container (Menu)?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, synchronization, wrapper

I am, for my own delight, trying to think of a good way to make an easier method of using the Windows API menus. While I did find [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/471662/Windows-Development-in-Cplusplus-working-with-menu), and might actually differentiate types of menu items by class, I'm kind of going for something like this:

---

**Description**

```
class MenuItem {...};

class MenuBar { //for the main menu of a window (file, help, etc)
    std::list<MenuItem> items; //and whatever else
};

class PopupMenu { //for dropdown (and possibly context) menus
    std::list<MenuItem> items; //and whatever else
};
```

The `MenuItem` class has functions such as `check()`, `disable()`, `setText()`, as well as more general ones such as `setType()` (string, bitmap, separator) and `setState` (enabled, checked, defaulted).

The `Menu` classes themselves would, in my vision, provide functions like `appendStringItem()`, `appendItem`, `insertBitmapItem()`, and provide access to the items themselves. I was also debating whether to have a `Menu` base class, and while input is appreciated, it's not the topic of the question.

---

**Wanted Usage**

If this was just C++, I wouldn't have a problem. However, my problem arises in syncing my menu items with the ones Windows uses, as a change in my class doesn't automatically change the real menu item. In order for a menu item to change, it has to be given a menu, and either a position in that menu, or the ID of the item. This makes sense, but from a usage perspective, why shouldn't I be able to do this:

```
MenuBar menuBar; //pretend this is filled
menuBar.itemAt(2).setText("New text");
```

---

**Problem**

Well, the problem is that I would expect this to change the menu item on the actual menu, but it won't. I need some way of knowing the menu that owns the item, as each item has the ID stored internally.

I could do this inside of the appropriate insertion functions in `MenuBar`:

```
bool MenuBar::someInsertionFunction(unsigned index, MenuItem newItem) {
    newItem.setOwner(*this); //owner as a raw HMENU type, with *this converting
    items.emplace_back(index, newItem); //index checked, of course
}
```

With that done, I'd have to make each setter in `MenuItem` check to make sure the owner is valid, and if it is, update the item using the API functions. Likewise, in the getters, I'd be calling the API functions to get the current state, but only if the owner is valid. This allows the user to create their own list of `MenuItem`s and initialize a `Menu` through that. This method also allows the user full access to modify the internal items list without any consequences, as the `MenuItem` class does a good job of protecting itself.

But this goes against what I find a good concept: **Why should the contained objects know about what contains them?** Is there a design pattern that deals with this problem, or is my best bet breaking this "rule" for the sake of being able to have the menu items control themselves (and with that, other menu items), instead of being controlled by the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an answer that I like quite well, actually. It combines being able to let the menu item change itself while still keeping some protection on the other items.

First of all, `MenuItem` stores a function to change itself:

```
std::function<BOOL(UINT, LPMENUITEMINFO)> changeRealItem;
```

This function is based off the Windows API `SetMenuItemInfo`, but has a couple of parameters missing. That's because we're going to bind that in the `Menu` classes:

```
Menu() {
    //one menu item as an example
    item.changeRealItem = std::bind(
        NonWinapiFunction(SetMenuItemInfo), //explained below
        *this,                              //with *this converting to a HMENU
        std::placeholders::_1,              //first argument is the ID
        FALSE,                              //previous is an ID, not a position
        std::placeholders::_2               //second argument is pointer to info
    );
}
```

Now, in the `MenuItemClass`, I can do essentially this:

```
MENUITEMINFO info = *this; //passing *this as an HMENU causes address problems
changeRealItem(id(), &info);
```

As a proof of concept, I made a `MessageBox` example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <windows.h>

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
std::function<Ret(Args...)> NonWinapiFunction(Ret(*WINAPI func)(Args...)) {
    return std::function<Ret(Args...)>(func);
}

struct MenuItem {
    MenuItem(std::function<int(const char *)> func) : message(func){}

    void changeSomething(const char *text) const {
        message(text);
    }

private:
    std::function<int(const char *)> message;
};

struct Menu {
    Menu() : item(std::bind(NonWinapiFunction(MessageBox), nullptr, std::placeholders::_1, "Title", MB_OK)){}
    MenuItem &getItem() {
        return item;
    }

private:
    MenuItem item;
};

int main() {
    Menu menu;
    menu.getItem().changeSomething("I can't change other menu items!");
}
```

The last bit is about `NonWinapiFunction`. The problem is that you can't call `std::bind` on a function using the `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`) calling convention. In order to circumvent this, a variadic template is made to extract the return type and argument types from a function and return a `std::function` with the same signature, but with the right calling convention, which can then be used with `std::bind`.

The one other piece is the fact that an arbitrary ID can be passed into the function and the extra line required to pass the address of the winapi structure needed. I believe both can be solved in a generic way (as long as a conversion operator from the wrapper to the wrapped type exists), but I haven't quite got it all figured out yet.